# Lyx: Special Line Break Symbols after Beamer Frame Title and after Frame

Tags: beamer, lyx

From the LyX wiki, I saw unfamiliar symbols which are denoted with red box in screenshot:

[image]

Which command/menu does insert these marks?

FYI, one can find the example file from here: https://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/Examples/Beamer/Liv/beamer-simple.lyx

Comment: The first could be an end-of-paragraph indicator, which is toggled at Tools -> Preferences -> Look and feel -> Display -> Mark end of paragraphs. Don't know what the second is.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks but it's different thing. I have never seen these marks in other documents, so it's not related with preferences. When I check the option, end of paragraph mark appears but it looks like ¶.

Comment: Yes, I see that was a bad suggestion. I don't actually know what they are. I suspected the first symbol was related to `\pause`s/overlays, but that didn't seem entirely consistent. And I suspected the double line could indicate an end of frame, but it's used elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the curly arrow, you can use the command "separator-insert latexpar". To get the double-red bar thing, you can use "separator-insert parbreak".

You should not need to use those commands directly, so I don't suggest learning them. The files on the Wiki are from previous versions of LyX. When opening a file from a previous version of LyX, sometimes markup is added that isn't the natural way of doing something in the new version of LyX.

I suggest you use the Beamer files that are shipped with LyX. See Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations, as well as the other example beamer file in the examples directory.

Note that LyX 2.3.0 will have a hopefully more intuitive way of adding new frames. See [here](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX23#beamerui) for more information.

Comment: Perfect answer 10/10 Thank you very much. :)